# An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details. in visual basic 2010

Tags: vb.net

I am making a spelling bee program it contains a login system and have spent weeks trying to fix this certain error i am having here is my error:
An error occurred creating the form. See Exception.InnerException for details.  The error is: `The type initializer for 'Spelling_Bee_Programme.test' threw an exception`.

Here is my login code for the login system:

```
 Imports System.Data.OleDb 'imports system O.L.E.D.B(Object Linking and Embedding database) functions
 Public Class formlogin ' startes class formlogin for the whole form
 Public Shared db_connection As New OleDbConnection 'declares db_connection as global variable and sets as new system O.L.E.D.B(Object Linking and Embedding database) connection 

Public Sub cmdlogin_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdlogin.Click ' when cmdlogin button pressed do following
    Dim time_data As String 'declares time_data as datatype string
    Dim file As String = "E:\login.txt" ' creates varible "file" and sets value as directory location
    txtuser.Text = txtuser.Text.ToLower() 'This ensures that the username is converted to lowercase so database doesn't have a problem with random capitals being in a username
    txtpass.Text = txtpass.Text.ToLower() 'This ensures that the password is converted to lowercase so database doesn't have a problem with random capitals being in a password
    txtuser.Text = Trim(txtuser.Text) ' removes spaces at start and end of text in txtuser's text property
    txtpass.Text = Trim(txtpass.Text) ' removes spaces at start and end of text in txt
    formlogin.db_connection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source= H:\Spelling Bee Programme\Spelling Bee Programme\DBmainframe.mdb"
    If txtpass.Text = "" Then  ' clears textbox of passwordOr txtuser.text = ""  ' clears textbox of usernameThen 'If username or password textbox is empty then do following
        MsgBox("please enter a username or password") 'make a messagebox pop up and tell user that they have not entered anything in the textbox.
        db_connection.Close() 'closes database because the database being open just incase it is accidently left open to ensure no problems. 'closes database because the database being open just incase it is accidently left open to ensure no problems.
    ElseIf txtuser.Text = "root" And txtpass.Text = "password" Then 'if first condition is not meet check if username is equal to root and password is equal to password then do following which is not relient on database so that if problem with database. It is still possible to acess program as backup solution.
        MsgBox("welcome root") ' makes a message box pop up and tell the user a welcome message saying the account they are logged in as.
        Dim objwriter1 As New System.IO.StreamWriter(file, True) ' declares a the varible objwriter as system and pulls value of varible file which is directory of where to write data and true is write to file saying yes
        time_data = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString ' varible time_data's value equal to current time and date
        DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm dddd, dd MMMM yyyy") ' this line formates the current time and date
        objwriter1.WriteLine("root login @ " & time_data) 'appends that a recovery user logged in and time of login to file
        objwriter1.Close() ' closes file writing
        result.Show() ' show result from test form.
        'closes database because the database being open just incase it is accidently left open to ensure no problems.
    Else 'executes if condition not meet.
        'Try ' this attempts the following
        Dim SQLteacher As String = "SELECT * FROM teacher WHERE username = '" & txtuser.Text & "' AND teacher_password = '" & txtpass.Text & "'" ' This line states select everything from table(teacher) and where username is = what is in textbox username and password table is = to textbox password then compare for match but doesn't execute.
        Dim sqlcomteacher As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(SQLteacher, db_connection) 'setups connection settings for database
        Dim SQLpupil As String = "SELECT * FROM pupil WHERE username = '" & txtuser.Text & "' AND pupil_password = '" & txtpass.Text & "'" ' This line states select everything from table(teacher) and where username is = what is in textbox username and password table is = to textbox password then compare for match but doesn't execute.
        Dim sqlcompupil As New System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand(SQLpupil, db_connection) 'setups connection settings for database
        db_connection.Open() ' opens database
        Dim sqlreadteacher As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader = sqlcomteacher.ExecuteReader() 'executes database query
        Dim sqlreadpupil As System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataReader = sqlcompupil.ExecuteReader() 'executes database query
        If sqlreadpupil.Read() Then 'if match for a teacher account sucessful then do following
            MsgBox("Login Sucessful") 'make messagebox appear and say "Login SucessFul"
            Dim objwriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(file, True) 'declares the name of the file writer and uses variable file for location of writting of data and true to allow writting
            time_data = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString 'sets value of varible time_data = current time set on the computer
            DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm dddd, dd MMMM yyyy") 'structures time and data by Hours, Minutes, Days, months and Year 
            objwriter.WriteLine("Teacher login @ " & time_data) 'writes on current line on file being created a "pupil login @ and then inputs time and data from variable time_data 
            objwriter.Close() ' closes file writing operation
            My.Forms.test.Visible = True
            Me.Hide() 'closes current form "Formlogin"
            db_connection.Close() 'closes database because the database being open just incase it is accidently left open to ensure no problems.

        ElseIf sqlreadteacher.Read() Then 'if match for a student account sucessful then do following.
            MsgBox("Login Sucessful") 'make messagebox appear and say "Login SucessFul"
            Dim objwriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(file, True) 'declares the name of the file writer and uses variable file for location of writting of data and true to allow writting
            time_data = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString 'sets value of varible time_data = current time set on the computer
            DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm dddd, dd MMMM yyyy") 'structures time and data by Hours, Minutes, Days, months and Year 
            objwriter.WriteLine("pupil login @ " & time_data) 'writes on current line on file being created a "pupil login @ and then inputs time and data from variable time_data 
            objwriter.Close() ' closes file writing operation
            result.Show() 'opens form called "result"
            Me.Hide() 'closes current form "Formlogin"
            db_connection.Close() 'closes database because the database being open just incase it is accidently left open to ensure no problems.
        Else : db_connection.Close() : MsgBox("Your username or password was incorrect.") 'closes database because the database being open just incase it is accidently left open to ensure no problems.
        End If ' ends if statement
        'Catch ex As Exception ' if error do following
        'MessageBox.Show("Failed to connect to Database.. System Error Message:  " & ex.Message, "Database Connection Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error) 'makes messagebox popup and say "Failed to connect to database... System error message:" shows error message and code for user to give back to us.
        db_connection.Close() 'closes database because the database being open just incase it is accidently left open to ensure no problems.
        'End Try 'ends 'try statement
    End If ' ends if statement
End Sub ' ends subprocedure.

Private Sub cmdcancel_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdcancel.Click 'when cancel button is clicked do following in subprocedure
    db_connection.Close()
    End 'ends whole program
End Sub 'ends subprocedure
End Class 'ends whole form procedure
```

Would love any advice on how to fix this error if possible.

Comment: The exception tells you the next step: look at the InnerException for details. So what does that InnerException show?

Comment: That's some dense code, have you considered refactoring it to fewer, well named methods?

Comment: This code works fine for me. Can you show us the test?

Comment: Where is "Public Sub New(ByVal argA As Object, ByVal argB As Object, ByVal mode As FormMode)     InitializeComponent() EndSub"? </br> This is a must for windows forms designer to work.

Answer (score 0):

The code in test isn't finished but take a look incase it is something there:

Imports System.Data.OleDb
Public Class test
    Dim vbscore As Integer
    Dim FILE_NAME As String = "E:\results.txt"
    Dim sql As String
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    Dim dr As OleDb.OleDbDataReader
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    Dim cb As OleDb.OleDbCommandBuilder = Nothing
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim time = Now.ToShortTimeString
    Public Shared Definition() As Label = {test.lbldefinition1, test.lbldefinition2, test.lbldefinition3, test.lbldefinition4, test.lbldefinition5, test.lbldefinition6, test.lbldefinition7, test.lbldefinition8, test.lbldefinition9, test.lbldefinition10}

```
Private Sub cmdsubmit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdsubmit.Click
    Dim da As OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter
    sql = "SELECT * FROM word"
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, formlogin.db_connection)
    Dim ds As New DataSet
    formlogin.db_connection.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source= E:\Spelling Bee Programme\Spelling Bee Programme\DBmainframe.mdb" 'uses varible from formlogin db_connection equal to software provider for database and location of database.
    '------------------------------------------------------- fills dataset words below ----------------------------------------------
    Dim dataset As DataTable = New DataTable("word")

    formlogin.db_connection.Open() 'uses variable from formlogin db_connection to open database
    da.Fill(ds, "words")
    formlogin.db_connection.Close()
    formlogin.db_connection.Open() 'uses variable from formlogin db_connection to open database

    vbscore = 0 ' resets value to ensure that you can not get a score over 20 which is the maximum value if you got every question right.
    Dim wordsarray() As TextBox = {txt1, txt2, txt3, txt4, txt5, txt6, txt7, txt8, txt9, txt10}
    Dim reviewscore() As String = {lblscorereview1.Text, lblscorereview2.Text, lblscorereview3.Text, lblscorereview4.Text, lblscorereview5.Text, lblscorereview6.Text, lblscorereview7.Text, lblscorereview8.Text, lblscorereview9.Text, lblscorereview10.Text}
    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To 9
        wordsarray(i).Text = wordsarray(i).Text.ToUpper()
        i = i + 1
    Next
    i = 0
    For i = 0 To 9
        If wordsarray(i).Text = "" Then
            MsgBox("Please Fill in all the TextBoxes")
            wordsarray(i).Focus()
            formlogin.db_connection.Close()
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf wordsarray(i).Text = ds.Tables("words").Rows(i).Item(1) Then
            vbscore = vbscore + 2 'adds 2 to varible "vbscore" if correct
            reviewscore(i) = vbscore
            lblresult.Text = Val(lblresult.Text) + Val(i)
            formlogin.db_connection.Close()
        End If
    Next
    Dim objwriter As New System.IO.StreamWriter(FILE_NAME, True)
    Dim tbscore As DataTable = New DataTable("score")
    Dim cmdInsert As New OleDbCommandBuilder(da)
    sql = "SELECT * FROM result"
    da = New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, formlogin.db_connection)
    formlogin.db_connection.Open()
    da.Fill(ds, "score")
    ds.Tables("score").Rows(0).Item(0) = formlogin.txtuser.Text
    ds.Tables("score").Rows(1).Item(1) = tbscore
    da.Update(ds, "score")
    formlogin.db_connection.Close()
    time = DateTime.Now.ToLongDateString
    DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss dddd, dd MMMM yyyy")
    objwriter.WriteLine(formlogin.txtuser.Text & " score = " & vbscore & " attempted test at " & time)
    objwriter.WriteLine()
    objwriter.Close()
    formlogin.db_connection.Close()
    MsgBox("Thank you for taking part in the test you're score was " & vbscore) ' shows partisapent a thank you message and what score they got in the test.
    Me.Close()
    formlogin.Show()
End Sub
Private Function Mark(ByVal InputtedWord As String, ByVal DBWord As String) As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim wrongletters As Integer
    Dim InputCharacter As Char
    Dim DbChar As Char
    Dim inputcounter As Integer
    Dim dbcounter As Integer
    Dim inputtextlength As Integer
    Dim dbtextlength As Integer
    Dim maxtextlength As Integer
    InputtedWord = InputtedWord.ToUpper
    inputtextlength = InputtedWord.Length
    DBWord = DBWord.ToUpper
    dbtextlength = DBWord.Length
    If inputtextlength >= dbtextlength Then
        maxtextlength = inputtextlength
    Else
        maxtextlength = dbtextlength
    End If
    inputcounter = 0
    dbcounter = 0
    For i = 0 To maxtextlength - 1
        InputCharacter = InputtedWord(inputcounter)
        DbChar = DBWord(dbcounter)
        If InputCharacter <> DbChar Then
            wrongletters = wrongletters + 1
        End If
        If inputcounter <> inputtextlength - 1 Then
            inputcounter = inputcounter + 1
        End If
        If dbcounter <> dbtextlength - 1 Then
            dbcounter = dbcounter + 1
        End If

    Next i

    If wrongletters >= 2 Then
        Mark = "0"
    ElseIf wrongletters = 1 Then
        Mark = "1"
    Else : Mark = "2"
    End If
End Function


Private Sub test_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cbWeek.SelectedIndexChanged
    If cbWeek.SelectedItem = "" Then
        MsgBox("Please select a week and then press load to start the test")
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnload_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnload.Click
    For Me.i = 0 To 9
        Definition(i).Text = ds.Tables("word").Rows(i).Item(0)
    Next
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: I fixed this error basically i accidentally added break points on every single line of code removed them all when i realized and fixed it